# How to pass grant-type with login parameters (OAuth 2.0)

Tags: .net, angular, oauth-2.0

The API I am using needs these parameters to authorize users:

Example 1 :

grant_type: password

UserName: user

Password: PWD

whereas when I send those three parameters via HTTP the API receives only two parameters with user name taking the value of the grant type and the password's value equals the value of the user name

so if I send the parameters in "Example 1" This is what it receives:

UserName: password

Password: user

So what is the correct way to pass auth type with the parameters

```js
   login(grant_type,userName, password) {
        let user = new Login(grant_type,userName,password);
        return this.http.post(this.loginEndPoint, user);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you provide us the code where you make the api request? It will make it easier to answer this question.

Comment: I edited my question..I added the code you requested